# Grizzly and Jersey are hiding my other annotations

Tags: jersey, grizzly

we have to update a Spring project where we need to embed a https server which supports SSL protocols and cipher suites selection.

My setup is : Spring 3.2.4, jersey 1.15.1 and Grizzly 1.9.60

The main problem that our resource class is calling some components which are expecting annotations.  But Grizzly seems to ignore the non-jersey REST annotations. So my custom annotations aren't transmitted at all.

I was wondering if you can give a an idea on how to work past this:

- is it possible to configure Jersey so it won't use annotations (maybe a xml or java config), hopefully keeping my own annotations to be transmitted down the line ?
- or it is possible to manually add the annotations on the method call ?

I recently tried this with Jetty 1.9.2 and jersey2 and it seems I have the same result. The only thing that worked was a SimpleServerFactory from Jersey 1, but like I said it didn't provide customizable SSL parameters.

Please someone :) ...

Comment: I am still not sure what happened there, (i am guessing different Java versions handle annotations differently?) but I took a different route and created a custom SSL Context with a custom SSL Engine where I could customize all the stuff that I wanted. So it turned out for the better.

Answer (score 0):

OK, just posting here maybe it will help someone. I finally got my hands on the components code and I noticed that the called class was looking for annotations in the last three stack traces.

What happened was Grizzly was adding a proxy of some kind, and that causes the three stack traces not to be enough and the annotations were not sent through.